# How to add year and month to Entry URL Format

Tags: url, entry, slug

I'd like to make the Entry URL format of a channel look like this: /news/2015/06/my-slug-here

What would I need to enter into the Entry URL Format field in order to do this?

The closest I could manage was this:

```
news/{postDate|date("Y")}/{slug}
```

But that only outputs this: /news/2015/my-slug-here

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close! For the month part you need `postDate|date("m")` ([this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has the php date formats).

```
news/{postDate|date("Y")}/{postDate|date("m")}/{slug}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this also work? `news/{postDate|date("Y/m")}/{slug}`  ... You'd put the slash inside the date format, so it won't have to parse `postDate` twice.

Comment: Thanks Marion, that worked great. Lindsey's suggestion worked too, thanks.

Comment: @Lindsey Hadn't thought of that, but nice improvement.